# Sorting the line according to first n columns in descending order

Tags: linux, sorting

I am having a file with mixed columns, and I am trying to sort the lines with keeping the first 4 fields as keys and then sorting them as descending based on column 5:

```
file1.txt

AAAA 2 X Q 0.20
AAAA 2 X W 0.45
AAAA 2 X E 0.21
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C W 0.92
AAAA 2 C E 0.0001
AAAA 2 X Q 0.20
AAAA 2 X W 0.55
AAAA 2 X E 0.27
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C W 0.82
AAAA 2 C E 0.04
AAAA 3 X Q 0.40
AAAA 3 X W 0.05
AAAA 3 X E 0.23
AAAA 3 C Q 0.33
```

What I want at the end is:

```
AAAA 2 X Q 0.20
AAAA 2 X Q 0.20
AAAA 2 X W 0.55
AAAA 2 X W 0.45
AAAA 2 X E 0.27
AAAA 2 X E 0.21
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C W 0.92
AAAA 2 C W 0.82
AAAA 2 C E 0.04
AAAA 2 C E 0.0001
AAAA 3 X Q 0.40
AAAA 3 X W 0.05
AAAA 3 X E 0.23
AAAA 3 C Q 0.33
```

For this one, I am sorting the file and keeping the first 4 field as keys:

```
sort -rnk1,4 -rnk5 file1.txt
```

However, it doesn't completely sort, as I want to keep the same first 4 fields together, in its output, one of them ( marked with ** to show it) is in different place:

```
AAAA 2 X Q 0.20
AAAA 2 X W 0.55
AAAA 2 X W 0.45
AAAA 2 X E 0.27
AAAA 2 X E 0.21
AAAA 2 X Q 0.20  ******
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C W 0.92
AAAA 2 C W 0.82
AAAA 2 C E 0.04
AAAA 2 C E 0.0001
AAAA 3 X Q 0.40
AAAA 3 X W 0.05
AAAA 3 X E 0.23
AAAA 3 C Q 0.33
```

How can I sort this file properly and without these unsorted ones?

Comment: The problem is your field 4 has no sort relationship to the other 5. It is neither sorted in an ascending or descending order with respect to the other two. You can get close with `sort -k1,2 -k3r -k5r file1.txt`, but field 4 provides no help.

Comment: @bapors, Does the answer solve your problem?

Comment: yes,accepting the answer now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first sort the file from column 1 to 5 and as you are considering column1-4 as key so any tie should be clear up by comparing the value of key(i.e. column1-4)

```
sort -rk1,5 -nk1,4 file1.txt
```

The answer coming is:

```
AAAA 3 X W 0.05
AAAA 3 X Q 0.40
AAAA 3 X E 0.23
AAAA 3 C Q 0.33
AAAA 2 X W 0.55
AAAA 2 X W 0.45
AAAA 2 X Q 0.20
AAAA 2 X Q 0.20
AAAA 2 X E 0.27
AAAA 2 X E 0.21
AAAA 2 C W 0.92
AAAA 2 C W 0.82
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C Q 0.24
AAAA 2 C E 0.04
AAAA 2 C E 0.0001
```

Comment: That's a good try, but does not match **"What I want at the end is:"**

Comment: It is further enhancement on what you want i guess. Your only requirement was to use the first four field as key and ordering 5th column in reverse order in the same key, you did not mention the order of first four fields. Also the answer that you wanted does not even have any sort of order for the first four field. The only thing is same keys are adjacent to each other. The solution that i have provided has the first4 columns also in sorted order which is better.